# Amazon Fire TV Stick 4k : jellyfin android tv 0.15.9 : SSL-Handshake failed

Tags: jellyfin

While entering a server address in Jellyfin-App on Fire TV Stick the error-message "SSL-Handshake failed" appears.
I am not sure but a week ago this was no issue...
Web access on a browser works, even the app on iphone runs...

Is there anything I have overseen?